# logic behind using temp table instead of group by in sub query

Tags: sql-server

In my  table country :

```
name|gdp|city
-------------
S.A |60 |amr
S.A |60 |amb
US  |200|ken
US  |70 |mas
aus |80 |po
aus |90 |tr
```

I want to get the country whose gdp is lower than 100.
when I use (2) it doesnt work and gives error because it returns multiple values which have to be compared to where condition.when I use (1) it works even though the sub query still gives back multiple values which are compared to 100.
What is the logic behind it please explain because I am new to sql. how is subquery in (1) different from (2)

- **(1)**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
           name
    FROM country a
    WHERE 100 > (SELECT SUM(gdp)FROM country b WHERE a.name = b.name);
```

- **(2)**

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
           name
    FROM country a
    WHERE 100 > (SELECT SUM(gdp)FROM country b GROUP BY name);
```

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

Comment: Even if you are summing the GDP for each Country they are all higher than 100

Comment: What does this question have to do with temporary tables, as your subject says?

Comment: Did any of the posted answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using (2): You are getting multiple values in the Subquery, as you are not having WHERE condition. You are getting multiple countries and corresponding sum. So, you are getting error.

When you are using (1): You are getting single value in Subquery, as you are getting single gdp as you are applying filter at country level. For each country, you are getting single  sum only. So, you are not getting error.

Answer (score 0):

The sub-query in query number 1 does not return multiple values. What you have there is called a "correlated sub-query". The sub-query has a `WHERE` clause that relates the results of the sub-query (the "inner" query) to the main query (the "outer" query). It's this bit `WHERE a.name = b.name`. Functionally, that query is run on a row-by-row basis where the `name` values match, and the sub-query only returns the single result for that `name` value. You'll notice that you can't run the sub-query by itself, because it needs to get the `name` value from the outer query in order to work.

In query number 2, if you run the sub-query by itself, it will return a list of summed `gdp` values. One column, with several rows. The `GROUP BY` clause is telling the query to `SUM` the results by `name`, but the result set doesn't contain the `name` value, so it's just a list of numbers. The outer query has no way of knowing *which* row of that result set you want to compare to `100`, and so it throws the error that you received.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you're after a `HAVING` here:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Country ([name] varchar(3),
                          gdp smallint,
                          city varchar(3));
INSERT INTO dbo.Country (name,
                         gdp,
                         city)
VALUES ('S.A', 60, 'amr'),
       ('S.A', 60, 'amb'),
       ('US ', 200, 'ken'),
       ('US ', 70, 'mas'),
       ('aus', 80, 'po '),
       ('aus', 90, 'tr ');
GO

SELECT C.name
FROM dbo.Country C
GROUP BY C.name
HAVING SUM(C.gdp) < 100 

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.Country;
```

As you want rows where  "the country gdp is lower than 100" this returns no rows, as there are no countries where the **`SUM`** of the `gdp` is **lower** than 100. (`S.A` has `120`, `US` has `270`, and `aus` has `170`).

If the `gbp` of a Country (not the City) is worked out differently, you may need to use a different aggregate function (`AVG`, `MAX`?) or a completely different method. if so, you should *explain* which rows you are expecting in your question and ***why***.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted. If you do feel this can be improved please do comment so that I, and the OP, can learn from your thoughts. Thanks.